# How to use a "native addon" (SSGI)

Tags: add-on, eevee-render-engine, installation

I just purchased [SSGI](https://app.gumroad.com/d/2e827ab86bc996da30d71ef057258d3a) on Gumroad which is a global illumination addon for Evee. I have a question about the installation. I can install the "old addons" (Screenshot 1) as usual: preferences/addons. But the "SSGI Native 1.13" obviously works differently. There is blender 2.93 in the folder (Screenshot 2). Does "native" mean the addon is already pre-installed? If so, how does it work? There is still the principled BSDF in the shader editor, which should be replaced by the SSGI node (screenshot). I don't find any other option to enable SSGI. And besides that, there is no way in the preferences/addons menu to install the addon, which tells me, it should actually be there already. (I already asked the support, but maybe it's quicker if someone here knows the answer already.)

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: The link takes me to a page saying I’ve viewed the resource before, and must input my email. I most certainly have not viewed it before, and will not input my email. What do you mean the addon works “differently” than the old versions? All add-ons install to one of two places and are enabled the same way. What good does showing us the executable in the Blender folder do? We already know what that folder looks like. Please review https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/addons.html No add-on can add or remove nodes from Blender, so this functionality description is wrong.

Comment: If you're having a problem with a third-party addon you'll have to ask the addon's author for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native means native C++ code. Native code is compiled to work directly with the OS. This requires a special build of Blender, not an add-on. As a result, code works faster and performant, but build can be unstable and in this case outdated.

The functionality of the "add-on" is inside of build, so there is no way to turn it on or off.

[image]